# Kotlin debug issue for intellij

Tags: kotlin, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a value in IntelliJ and using evaluate expression option. Now the evaluation throws exception when trying to get simple class information of headers.

error is:

> org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.CompilationErrorException : Could not
> load module  in an
> attempt to find deserializer for symbol
> kotlinx.serialization/noCompiledSerializer|noCompiledSerializer(kotlin.String){}kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer<*>[0].

`requestHeaders as Map<String, List<String>?>`

this is the line I am trying to evaluate.

I have tried including the mentioned library in `gradle.build.kt` as *implementation* and as *runtime* but both solution does not work.

I have tried to evaluate using java and it works there but my code is in kotlin so would help evaluating expression as is.

Let me know if someone needs more info.

Comment: Please file an issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Hey floks I resolved this issue by resetting the IDE to factory settings.